# bundler clean downloaded gits

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm using latest bundler with a lot of :git => ... in my Gemfile. Bundler does not seem to remove old/ unused git repositories it downloaded. Also I couldn't find a simple "bundle clean", just like "gem clean". Of course this would only work properly when using a separatestorage per project, but this is how I do it. So I wonder what's the best way to have bundler clean old data? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the bundler team and the feature will be implemented in bundler 2.1.  :)